# Graphics prepared with Sweave and text disorder

Tags: r, sweave

I am preparing a report using Sweave, it is really beautiful, but the first introductory words of my pdf-file appear after the first R-plot! How to fix it?

I would like to add that I've already tried `ReadOrder = TRUE`, but it failed.

Comment: you have given no information that can really allow anyone to help. But if your plot is in a latex figure environment, then the meaning of that environment is to allow latex to move the figure, typically to the top of the page.

Comment: May be you are using knitr, not Sweave, and it is almost certain that your plot  is inserted as a figure environment, but without a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  is just guessing the problem. Hardly our powers of divination reach also the solution without really knowing the problem.